# how to display this this echo without getting error in line 113?

Tags: php, echo

how to fix this echo error ? just need a hind or a little help here , 
users cannot see the table if they are not logged in but otherwise they can if they are logged .....how to fix?

```
<?php
    session_start();

     if ( isset( $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) == "0" )
    {
    echo "You are not logged in.";
    }
    else  {
    echo '<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">';
    echo '<tr>';}
    echo ' <td width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>#</strong></td>';
     echo '<td width="53%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Topic</strong></td>';
     echo '<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Views</strong></td>';
     echo '<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Replies</strong></td>';
     echo '<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>';
     echo '</tr>;'
     }
    ?>
```

Comment: Get rid of your extra bracket.

Comment: what is the error and what is lin 113

Comment: Your problem is in this line => `echo '<tr>';}`. Change it to `echo '<tr>';`. Give that a whirl and get back to me.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\hawties\forum.php on line 116

Comment: Another error: change `echo '</tr>;'` to `echo '</tr>';`

Comment: @IskonoMorto See my answer below. Should work.

Comment: @IskonoMorto I did not add anything to your code, as I assumed that the table was not to be closed, in thinking you had other code below that. Am glad it worked out for you, cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were 2 errors.

An extra bracket in:

```
echo '<tr>';}
```

changed to:

```
echo '<tr>';
```

and your semi-colon was at the wrong place:

```
 echo '</tr>;'
```

Changed to:

```
 echo '</tr>';
```

Here is the complete reworked code from your posted code:

```
<?php
   session_start();

 if ( isset( $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) == "0" )
{
echo "You are not logged in.";
}
else  {
echo '<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">';
echo '<tr>';
echo ' <td width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>#</strong></td>';
 echo '<td width="53%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Topic</strong></td>';
 echo '<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Views</strong></td>';
 echo '<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Replies</strong></td>';
 echo '<td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>';
 echo '</tr>';
 }
?>
```

Comment: worked really good as the way i wanted while logged in but it dysplays the table values without poutting em inside table while logging off, ill try to fix it up
many thanks Fred

Comment: @IskonoMorto You're welcome Iskono. Can you post the rest of your code? Might only be a simple addition, or you can ask another question. I will be happy to have a look at it.

Comment: Here's the rest :

 

// Start looping table row
 while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
 ?>
<tr>
 <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="view.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['topic']; ?></a><BR></td>
 <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['view']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['reply']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
 </tr>

Comment: @IskonoMorto where is it, I don't see it.

Comment: <?php
// Exit looping and close connection 
 }
 mysql_close();
 ?>

<tr>
 <td colspan="5" align="right" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><a href="create.php"><strong>Create New Topic</strong> </a></td>
 </tr>
 </table>

Comment: @IskonoMorto *am thinking*...

Comment: @IskonoMorto Is `session_start();` inside and on top of all `.php` files?

Comment: ya thats the full code

Comment: @IskonoMorto I meant inside `view.php` and `create.php` files? Is `session_start();` inside those also?

Comment: ya , the has it too, but i figured out the the reason of showing out tables value while logging out , here :
<tr>
 <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><a href="view.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>"><?php echo $rows['topic']; ?></a><BR></td>
 <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['view']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['reply']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['datetime']; ?></td>
 </tr>
now i am trying to figure out how to show only whle logging

Comment: While working with a **working copy of your code**, you have a few options. You can try changing `if ( isset( $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) == "0" )` **to** `if ( !isset( $_SESSION['loggedin'] ) )` **or change** `echo "You are not logged in.";` **to** `die ("You are not logged in.");` **or** `echo "You are not logged in."; exit;`

Comment: die ("You are not logged in."); worked fine ! really thanks for your helps !

Comment: @IskonoMorto That is good news Iskono, I'm glad I was able to help, and you're very much welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']))
    {
        echo "You are not logged in.";
    }
    else  
    {
        echo '<table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                <tr>
                    <td width="6%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>#</strong></td>
                    <td width="53%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Topic</strong></td>
                    <td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Views</strong></td>
                    <td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Replies</strong></td>
                    <td width="13%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
                </tr>
               </table>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: this worked , fixed the error message but i can see whats inside the table even if i am logged off

Comment: try now with updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
  echo '</tr>;'
     }
    ?>
```

the last line it should be like

```
  echo '</tr>';
     }
    ?>
```